# How to serialise a Drools CEP KieSession

Tags: drools, kie

We are running a drools CEP session.

We are unable to serialise the session while fireUntilHalt is being executed. Since the rules are time based we have use fireUntilHalt. While serialising the rules we intermittently get errors as posted here
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1471

Is there is clean way to serialise the rules while using fireUntilHalt.

Comment: Since Mario Fusco from the Drools team has answered the issue, what do you expect?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any workaround available or how have others handled this scenario.

Comment: You cannot expect a serialization running in parallel with regular usage to produce anything meaningful. At least, you'd have to lock; so you might as well call halt, serialize, and fireUntilHalt again.